# AngularJS ng-click function not bringing info to new view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying to make a friends list. I have it set up so a user can search for friends and click on their image to see their profile, this takes them to the profile where there is information displayed that I have in an array in my service. I have an 'add friend' button that when clicked, changes into a 'remove friend' button and is supposed to add that friend to a new html view. There are a few problems I am running into that I can't seem to figure out.
1) the button is changing for every user when only clicked on 1 users profile. 
2) the user is not being added to the friends view.

Here is my service code:

```js
var friendProfile = {};
  var userFriends = [];

  this.addFriend = function(profileObj) {
      userFriends.push(profileObj);
  };

  this.removeFriend = function(profileObj) {
    for( var i = userFriends.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (userFriends[i].name === profileObj.name) {
        userFriends.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  };
```

Here is my controller:

```js
$scope.friendProfile = {};
  $scope.userFriends = [];
  $scope.currentlyFriends = false;

  $scope.addFriend = function(profileObj) {
    mainSvrc.addFriend($scope.friendProfile );
    $scope.currentlyFriends = true;
  };

  $scope.removeFriend = function(profileObj) {
    mainSvrc.removeFriend
    ($scope.friendProfile);
    $scope.currentlyFriends = false;
  };
```

Here is the HTML:

```html
/*profile view with buttons*/

<button class="friend-profbutton"
        ng-click="addFriend(friendProfile)"
        ng-hide="currentlyFriends">ADD FRIEND</button>

        <button class="friend-profbutton"
        ng-click="removeFriend(friendProfile)"
        ng-show="currentlyFriends">REMOVE FRIEND</button>
    </div>


/*friends list it should be coming too*/
        <div ng-repeat="friend in userFriends" ui-sref="friend-profile({id:friend.id})" class="picture-wrapper">
            <img ng-src="{{friends.profileUrl}}" class="friend-profilePic">
            <div class="box">
              <div class="overlay">
                <p class="overlay-text">{{friends.name}}</p>
                <a class="view-proflink">View Profile</a>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```js
.state('friend-search', {
            url: '/friend-search',
            templateUrl: '/views/templates/friend-search.html',
            controller: 'friendSearchCtrl'
        })

        .state('friend-profile', {
          url: '/friend-profile/:id',
          templateUrl: 'views/templates/friend-profile.html',
          controller: 'friendProfileCtrl'
        })

        .state('friends', {
            url: '/friends',
            templateUrl: '/views/templates/friends.html',

        });
```

Can anyone see what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like a caching issue, how you are routing from friend list view to profile view. Are you using ui-router or ng-route

Comment: @SanketBajoria I am using UI-Router

Comment: Can we have your $stateProvider .state from the profile page please?

Comment: @Wandrille I added it above

Comment: your function addFriend from your service works well? because it returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

In your service, you returns nothing.

Can you try in your service:

```
  this.userFriends = [];

  this.addFriend = function(profileObj) {
      this.userFriends.push(profileObj);
  };

  this.removeFriend = function(profileObj) {
    for( var i = this.userFriends.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (this.userFriends[i].name === profileObj.name) {
        this.userFriends.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  };
```

and in your controller:

```
  $scope.friendProfile = {};
  $scope.userFriends = mainSvrc.userFriends ;
  $scope.currentlyFriends = false;

  $scope.addFriend = function(profileObj) {
    mainSvrc.addFriend($scope.friendProfile );
    $scope.userFriends = mainSvrc.userFriends ;
    $scope.currentlyFriends = true;
  };

  $scope.removeFriend = function(profileObj) {
    mainSvrc.removeFriend($scope.friendProfile);
    $scope.currentlyFriends = false;
    $scope.userFriends = mainSvrc.userFriends ;
  };
```

and correct:

```
<div ng-repeat="friend in userFriends" class="picture-wrapper">
    <div ui-sref="friend-profile({id:friend.id})">
        <img ng-src="{{friend.profileUrl}}" class="friend-profilePic">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="overlay">
                <p class="overlay-text">{{friend.name}}</p>
                <a class="view-proflink">View Profile</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to have made some progress. This brought over my box and overlay, but didn't bring any user information I have stored in another array over. Could it be because I am pushing it to an empty array?

Comment: you have ng-repeat="friend in userFriends"
So you need to write friend.something and not friends.something

Comment: still the same issue. I can look further into it. The fact it is bring over the box and overlay is awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Somewhat. The button is still changing from 'add' to 'remove' on all friend profiles when it is only clicked on one of them and after clicking the button, the user data is not coming through, just the overlay.

Comment: I am thinking my views are messed up or I am not pulling data from my original array. Because everything you have helped me with is working, but it is not pulling the id from the array I already have into the new userFriends array.

Comment: Have you checked if friend.id is the good value?
If you replace ui-sref="friend-profile({id:friend.id})" by another state, is it working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124910/discussion-between-wandrille-and-talonhughes).